# Publishing iOS app for another party

Tags: ios, xcode8, apple-developer

I was approached to build an iOS app for a company. What would be the best way to go about this when developing and managing the project?

1. Would I publish this under my developer profile?
2. Should they create their own developer profile and have them give me the credentials?
3. Should we get a developer account and be members of a team?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about marketing, not programming.

Comment: It's completely about programming

Comment: No, it's about publishing. Neither programming nor programming tools can help you with that. Anyway, my vote is just that: a vote. Time will tell whether the community agrees with me or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes!! Client needs to create their own Apple Developer Account for current and future applications.

They needs to have paid account to publish App on store. Meanwhile either they can add you as developer or share the original credentials with your so you can sign the application with development and distribution certificates for Notification and publish.

It's a one time JOB, but trust me best option for You and your Client as well.

[Here is your start](https://www.raywenderlich.com/127936/submit-an-app-part-1).

Answer (score 1):

id go with option 2 .... definitely not 1 so that they 'own' the final outcome and also you want to keep your account free of external dependencies

Answer (score 0):

There are three ways you can go about release an app for client:

- Release the app on your account and have a written agreement between yourself and the client to forward profits from the app to the client.
- Ask them to give your Apple ID access to their account so you can upload it to their account (they shouldn't really give you *their* credentials for security reasons.
- Upload the app to your account and once its gone through the review process you can then transfer ownership of the app from your account to theirs. ([Documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/TransferringAndDeletingApps.html))